# Determining a value to form a projector

Tags: linear-algebra, projection

I am working on a question in which I have been given that $P\in\mathcal{L}(V)$ is a non-zero projector. Where I need to determine all $x\in\mathbb{C}$ such that: $P^3 + xP^2 - (2-x)P + I_V$ is a projector.

I know that for something to be a projector that $P=P^2$
I let Y be : $Y = P^3 + xP^2 - (2-x)P + I_V$
And to make it easier to work with let $P^2 = P$

Which gives me $Y = P(2x-1) + I_V$

From this I got that $Y^2 = (P(2x-1) + I_V)^2$

Equation the two gives:
\begin{eqnarray}P(2x-1) + I_V &=& (P(2x-1) + I_V)^2\\
P(2x-1) + I_V &=& P^2(2x-1)^2 + 2PI_V(2x-1) + I_V^2\\
P(2x-1) &=& P^2(2x-1)^2 + 2P(2x-1)\\
0 &=& P^2(2x-1)^2 + 2P(2x-1)\end{eqnarray}
Now as P cannot be zero, we can find x.
So either: $(2x-1) = 0$ or $2x-1=0$
So thus $x=\frac{1}{2}$.
Is my working correct?
I am mainly unsure whether I am allowed to use that $P^2 = P$ to simplify the expression.

Comment: Don't you get $Y = P +xP - (2+x)P +I = -P + I$?

Comment: @ElliotHerrington sorry accidently wrote the initial equation wrong the $(2+x)$ is $(2-x)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your second-to-last step, you got rid of the left side but did nothing to the right side, which is a mistake. After that, it needs to be clearer why you're concluding $2x-1=0$ from your projector equation. Also I would write scalars on the left of operators, not on the right. So you should go

$$ (2x-1)P=(2x-1)^2P^2+2(2x-1)P $$

$$ 0=(2x-1)^2P^2+1(2x-1)P $$

$$ 0=(2x-1)^2P+(2x-1)P $$

$$ 0=\big[(2x-1)^2+(2x-1)\big]P $$

$$ 0 = 2x(2x-1)P $$

From this, you get $x=0$ or $x=\frac{1}{2}$, which you can check manually are solutions.

---

You can also see when $Y=(2x-1)P+I$ is a projector with geometry instead of algebra. A projector is characterized by its image and kernel - it is the unique operator which acts as the identity on the image and annihilates the kernel. We can see $Y$ acts as the identity on $P$'s kernel, and as $2x$ on $P$'s image. For this to be a projector, $2x$ must be $0$ or $1$.